# extra button overlays on the flutter app that are like screen burns

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have been trying to use the Google Maps API to make a few personal projects and when I have created a basic homepage that shows the Map snapshot and two buttons, it looks like below where my buttons are the one directly below the map but the similar ones below are not coded and neither do they work like buttons, its like a screen burn , kindly refer the image below:

[image]

Here is the code :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng curLoc = LatLng(9.970630, 76.425110);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
        title: const Center(
          child: Text('Route Prediction'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            height: 300,
            child: GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition:
                  const CameraPosition(target: curLoc, zoom: 10),
              markers: {
                const Marker(markerId: MarkerId("You"), position: curLoc)
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('General User'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  'Emergency Vehicle',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: At what device have you tried to run your app?

Answer (score 0):

### Wrap `Scaffold` widget with `MaterialApp` widget

Running your code on my device did not reproduce the duplicate button issue that you showed i your screenshot, but I was receiving a `No Directionality error`:

[image: No Directionality Error]

I then noticed that you did not wrap your `Scaffold` with the `MaterialApp` widget. Please see [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html)

So what I did is I just wrapped the `Scaffold` widget with the `MaterialApp` widget and changed the parameter where the `Scaffold` widget is inserted into `home`.

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
//...The rest of the code
```

So your whole `main.dart` code should look like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng curLoc = LatLng(9.970630, 76.425110);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
          title: const Center(
            child: Text('Route Prediction'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              height: 300,
              child: GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition:
                const CameraPosition(target: curLoc, zoom: 10),
                markers: {
                  const Marker(markerId: MarkerId("You"), position: curLoc)
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('General User'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'Emergency Vehicle',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this, your app should be fine:

[image: Working App Screenshot]

I hope this helps!